# How to convert a u32 into a BoundedVec compatible format?

Tags: boundedvec, parse

I am using a BoundedVec as the id for a storage map, and intend to transform a u32 value into a compatible format. Is there a streamlined way to accomplish this, or should I split the u32 into smaller bits and insert them into the BoundedVec? If the latter is true, how should I go about this?

Comment: Why can you not use the `u32` as map key directly?

Comment: Currently, I have the storage setup with the u32 as the key, however, due to new requirements, the Ids may also include characters, hence the boundedvec (of u8). Instead of creating a separate storage for these new items, I am trying to modify the existing one. Then, I can distinguish the two different types either through an enum, or through a specific prefix.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SCALE codec to encode types into `Vec`. Then the `Vec` can be converted into a `BoundedVec`.

For example a `u32` (but it works the same for any other encodable type):

```rust
use codec::Encode;
use sp_core::ConstU32;
use sp_runtime::BoundedVec;

let value: u32 = 123;
let encoded: Vec<u8> = value.encode();
let bounded: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<4>> = encoded.try_into()?;
```

Note that the conversion from `Vec` to `BoundedVec` is fallible, in case that it does not fit into the bounded vec. There are also infallible functions like `BoundedVec::truncate_from`, but personally I would rather use the fallible version and return in an error case.

It is possible to use the [`MaxEncodedLen`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/trait.MaxEncodedLen.html) for testing to ensure that the `BoundedVec` is always long enough to hold the encoded values.